# Will controller block while making spring/hibernate call?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework, typesafe-activator

This is controller after creating project from activator template for Play and Spring sample.

#### Controller Code:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    public Result addBar() {
        Form<Bar> form = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest();
        Bar bar = form.get();
        barService.addBar(bar);
        return play.mvc.Controller.redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index());
    }
}
```

#### Bar Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BarServiceImpl implements BarService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addBar(Bar bar) {
        em.persist(bar);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Bar> getAllBars() {
        CriteriaQuery<Bar> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Bar.class);
        c.from(Bar.class);
        return em.createQuery(c).getResultList();
    }
}
```

#### Spring Hibernate configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("models");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        }});
        entityManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(Play.application().configuration().getString("db.default.url"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

My question is when controller calls `addBar` function in `barService` is it a blocking call? If yes then what should be the proper way of doing spring/hibernate integration in a Play application considering it is a sample code from Typesafe activator itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it blocks because JDBC does not have async/non-blocking support. And since Hibernate depends on JDBC, it inherits its blocking behavior. This is also [documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync):

> Common examples of such blocking operations are **JDBC calls**, streaming API, HTTP requests and long computations.

I highly recommend that you read the following documentation pages:

1. [JavaAsync: Handling asynchronous results](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAsync)
2. [Understanding Play thread pools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools)

I also recommend that you take a look at other very similar discussions here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32784410/4600